# Batch download tiles from a pictures

Tags: bash, macos, wget

I would like to download a pictures from a website using `bash` on `macOS` which is subdivided into smaller squared pictures, so called tiles. The link of each tile is:

```
http://whateverdomain.is/TileGroup$y/$z-$i-$x.jpg
```

where `$y` would be the number of the tile group usually between 1 and 6, `$z` is a constant (= 6), and
`$i` and `$x` describe the position for each column (i) and row (x), respectively.

I have two issues, I would like my script to go from column to column first, before changing the row. Now it does the complete opposite, see script below. It would go from `6-0-0` to `6-1-0`, instead to `6-0-1`, as well as to `6-2-0`, instead of `6-0-2` etc.

The second issue is, that each 95 tiles, the tile group `$y` changes, iterating by 1, from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, etc. However, my condition in the script does not seem to function. (I am not a programmer.)

How can I achieve that my script, first of all, goes from column to column before changing rows, and, secondly, how can I adjust the script to change the tile group by 1 after each 95 tile being downloaded?

This is my script:

```
((z = 6)) # zoom level
((k = 0)) # counter
((y = 1)) # tile group at start

for x in `seq 0 30`; do
  for i in `seq 0 38`; do
      wget -c -nc -E -nd http://whateverdomain.is/TileGroup$y/$z-$i-$x.jpg
      k = k + 1 # count each tile
      if [[ $k -eq 95 ]];
      then
        y = y + 1 # change tile group each 95th tile
      fi
      if [[ $y -eq 7 ]]; # tile group maxed out; stop
      then
        break
      fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions.

> How can I achieve that my script, first of all, goes from column to column before changing rows?

You have to change `x` and `i` in for loops, like this:

```
for i in `seq 0 30`; do
  for x in `seq 0 38`; do
      ...
  done
done
```

> how can I adjust the script to change the tile group by 1 after each
> 95 tile being downloaded?

Like this:

```
((k%95)) || ((y++))
```

Final script with this improvements:

```
((z = 6)) # zoom level
((k = 0)) # counter
((y = 1)) # tile group at start

for i in `seq 0 30`; do
  for x in `seq 0 38`; do
      wget -c -nc -E -nd http://whateverdomain.is/TileGroup$y/$z-$i-$x.jpg
      k = k + 1 # count each tile
      ((k%95)) || ((y++)) # change tile group each 95th tile
      if [[ $y -eq 7 ]];  # tile group maxed out; stop
      then
        break
      fi
  done
done
```

And a slightly more improved version:

```
z=6 # zoom level
k=0 # counter
y=1 # tile group at start

for i in {0..30}; do
  for x in {0..38}; do
      wget -c -nc -E -nd http://whateverdomain.is/TileGroup$y/$z-$i-$x.jpg
      ((k++))             # count each tile
      ((k%95)) || ((y++)) # change tile group each 95th tile
      ((y>z))  &&  break  # tile group maxed out; stop
  done
done
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, I like you approach as it seems to be minimal invasive to my code, which means I might easily understand what I did wrong given my original code. May you be so kind as to add your two code snippets to the original code so to have the entire code functional? I am still a bit unsure about where to add `((k%95)) || ((y++))`for example in my code. Sry, for my little knowledge.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sort your loop within a loop out - for example this should work:

```
x=6
y=0
z=0
ymax=7 # y bound
zmax=3 # z bound

while [ $y -lt $ymax ]
do
  z=0 #reset z
    while [ $z -lt $zmax ]
    do
      echo "x = $x y = $y z = $z"  # do stuff here
      z=$(( $z + 1 )) #increment z
    done
  y=$(( $y + 1 )) #increment y
done
```

output:

```
x = 6 y = 0 z = 0
x = 6 y = 0 z = 1
x = 6 y = 0 z = 2
x = 6 y = 1 z = 0
x = 6 y = 1 z = 1
x = 6 y = 1 z = 2
x = 6 y = 2 z = 0
x = 6 y = 2 z = 1
x = 6 y = 2 z = 2
x = 6 y = 3 z = 0
x = 6 y = 3 z = 1
x = 6 y = 3 z = 2
x = 6 y = 4 z = 0
x = 6 y = 4 z = 1
x = 6 y = 4 z = 2
x = 6 y = 5 z = 0
x = 6 y = 5 z = 1
x = 6 y = 5 z = 2
x = 6 y = 6 z = 0
x = 6 y = 6 z = 1
x = 6 y = 6 z = 2
```

You can change them to something better (e.g. count from 1, change lt to =< etc.) to suit.

More loops:

```
x=6
y=0
z=0
xmax=10 # x bound
ymax=7 # y bound
zmax=3 # z bound

while [ $x -lt $xmax ]
do
y=0 # reset y
  while [ $y -lt $ymax ]
  do
  z=0 #reset z
    while [ $z -lt $zmax ]
    do
      echo "x = $x y = $y z = $z"  # do stuff here
      z=$(( $z + 1 )) #increment z
    done
  y=$(( $y + 1 )) #increment y
done
x=$(( $x + 1))
done
```

output:

```
x = 6 y = 0 z = 0
x = 6 y = 0 z = 1
x = 6 y = 0 z = 2
x = 6 y = 1 z = 0
x = 6 y = 1 z = 1
x = 6 y = 1 z = 2
x = 6 y = 2 z = 0
x = 6 y = 2 z = 1
x = 6 y = 2 z = 2
x = 6 y = 3 z = 0
x = 6 y = 3 z = 1
x = 6 y = 3 z = 2
x = 6 y = 4 z = 0
x = 6 y = 4 z = 1
x = 6 y = 4 z = 2
x = 6 y = 5 z = 0
x = 6 y = 5 z = 1
x = 6 y = 5 z = 2
x = 6 y = 6 z = 0
x = 6 y = 6 z = 1
x = 6 y = 6 z = 2
x = 7 y = 0 z = 0
x = 7 y = 0 z = 1
x = 7 y = 0 z = 2
x = 7 y = 1 z = 0
x = 7 y = 1 z = 1
x = 7 y = 1 z = 2
x = 7 y = 2 z = 0
x = 7 y = 2 z = 1
x = 7 y = 2 z = 2
x = 7 y = 3 z = 0
x = 7 y = 3 z = 1
x = 7 y = 3 z = 2
x = 7 y = 4 z = 0
x = 7 y = 4 z = 1
x = 7 y = 4 z = 2
x = 7 y = 5 z = 0
x = 7 y = 5 z = 1
x = 7 y = 5 z = 2
x = 7 y = 6 z = 0
x = 7 y = 6 z = 1
x = 7 y = 6 z = 2
x = 8 y = 0 z = 0
x = 8 y = 0 z = 1
x = 8 y = 0 z = 2
x = 8 y = 1 z = 0
x = 8 y = 1 z = 1
x = 8 y = 1 z = 2
x = 8 y = 2 z = 0
x = 8 y = 2 z = 1
x = 8 y = 2 z = 2
x = 8 y = 3 z = 0
x = 8 y = 3 z = 1
x = 8 y = 3 z = 2
x = 8 y = 4 z = 0
x = 8 y = 4 z = 1
x = 8 y = 4 z = 2
x = 8 y = 5 z = 0
x = 8 y = 5 z = 1
x = 8 y = 5 z = 2
x = 8 y = 6 z = 0
x = 8 y = 6 z = 1
x = 8 y = 6 z = 2
x = 9 y = 0 z = 0
x = 9 y = 0 z = 1
x = 9 y = 0 z = 2
x = 9 y = 1 z = 0
x = 9 y = 1 z = 1
x = 9 y = 1 z = 2
x = 9 y = 2 z = 0
x = 9 y = 2 z = 1
x = 9 y = 2 z = 2
x = 9 y = 3 z = 0
x = 9 y = 3 z = 1
x = 9 y = 3 z = 2
x = 9 y = 4 z = 0
x = 9 y = 4 z = 1
x = 9 y = 4 z = 2
x = 9 y = 5 z = 0
x = 9 y = 5 z = 1
x = 9 y = 5 z = 2
x = 9 y = 6 z = 0
x = 9 y = 6 z = 1
x = 9 y = 6 z = 2
```

Comment: Thank you, bob, for your answer. What about `$x`? You seem to have miss the last variable in your proposed script. There are four variables, in the original post.

Comment: You just add the same loop as for y . I'll edit  the answer ....

Comment: @TilHund edit added. I'd probably add more variables to this and neaten it - however the principle is still the same - loop inner, reset inner, increment outer etc.

Comment: C-style for loops would be simpler. There's no reason to ignore the `bash` tag on the question and make this purely POSIX-compliant.

Comment: This works in bash. It wasn't about being compliant - they are happy to set a constant for seemingly no reason as an example. This wouldn't be how I would do it myself - however it still solves the issue they were having, often it's a thought process which is the thing lacking rather than technical capability.

Comment: Thank you, Bob, for your answer. The think with the constant is, that is is actually a variable, but in that part of the code it has the same value.